# Wordpress ignoring HHVM upload max file size

Tags: wordpress, nginx, upload, hhvm

I am having the following problem, I am running NGINX and HHVM (VM 3.9.1 rel):

Wordpress ignores my `/etc/hhvm/php.ini` configuration file which has the following directives:

```
;php options
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = /var/lib/hhvm/sessions
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
memory_limit = 600M
upload_max_filesize = 128M
post_max_size = 128M
max_input_time = 60
max_execution_time = 300
```

When I run `phpinfo()` I can see my upload file size reflected there.. however, when I try to upload any file through Wordpress, I receive an error that the maximum upload size is 0kb.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like you might be running into https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/4993. Try setting `hhvm.enable_zend_ini_compat=false` and see if that helps. (Also try setting it to `true`... I've forgotten what the default is, and which setting is supposed to help here.)

If that helps, please add a comment on this answer; if this issue is still the root cause of issues in 3.9, I'd like to change the default moving forward -- this was *supposed* to have been fixed.

Comment: Great! Yes this fixed it! Thank you so much Josh.

I've added it to both /etc/hhvm/php.ini and /etc/hhvm/server.ini

Now Wordpress allows uploads and respects the upload_max_filesize directive.

Comment: If you see "Maximum upload file size:." then setting the zend_ini_compat to false takes care of it. You'll then get a nice "Maximum upload file size: 20MB." or whatever your upload_max_filesize is. Also, if you still cannot upload make sure your uploads directory and has been chmod to the correct user. Example: `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data uploads`

Comment: Additionally I needed to update nginx.conf. `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` Inside the  http block add `client_max_body_size 50M` . Then restart nginx and hhvm and you should be good.